# How do I correctly use "getline(cin, input);"

Tags: c++, input, storage, getline

I am writing a program that is to convert text that a user gives. I have tried this method by itself in a test program and it works perfectly; however when I try to implement it into the larger program, the user cannot give the program an input to store. The relevant code is as follows:

```
int main()
{
    string str = "NULL";
    int mappings = 0;
    readMappings(mappings);
    receiveInput(str);
    displayInput(mappings, str);
    return 0;
}
void readMappings(int &count)
{
    ifstream readMappings;                                                  // Creates the function "readMappings"
    string filename;                                                        // Generates the filename variable to search for mapping document
    cout << "Enter the filename of the mapping document: ";
    cin >> filename;                                                        // User enters filename
    readMappings.open(filename);                                            // "readMappings" function opens the given mappings document
    while (!readMappings.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unsble to open file. Please enter a valid filename: ";     // If the user enters an invaled filename, the program will ask again
        cin >> filename;
        readMappings.open(filename);
    }   
    if (readMappings.good())                                                // Mapping document is successfully opened
    {
        readMappings >> count;                                              // Reads first line
    }
    readMappings.close();                                                   // If everything fails in this function, the document will close
}
void receiveInput(string &input)
{
    char correctness;
    do {
        cout << "\nPlease enter the text you would like to be converted to NATO:\n";
        getline(cin, input);
        cout << "You are about to convert: \"" << input << "\".\nIs this correct? (Y/N)" << endl;
        cin >> correctness;
    } while (correctness == 'N' || correctness =='n');
}
```

I thought it may have been the program waiting for another input from the user so I added a variable I assumed it would already fill, but it did not fix my solution.  In my opinion, the problem is in the receiveInput function, but I could be wrong.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Also, I am using function prototypes with correct reference variables.

Comment: Classic example of [mixing getline and stream extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems:

1) You're not checking for an EOF condition, after invoking `std::getline()`.

2) You are mixing together both `std::getline` and the `>>` operator. Now, there's actually nothing technically wrong with that, but both `std::getline` and the `>>` operator have very *nuanced* semantics, when it comes to error checking and input consuming, that you need to get 100% right, in order to correctly use them together.

Just replace your usage of the `>>` operator with `std::getline`, so you're using `std::getline` exclusively, and make sure to check for `fail`() or `eof`(). You will find plenty of examples of how to correctly check for end of file and failure conditions, with `std::getline`, here on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Can explain in more detail by what you mean by _Just replace usage of the `>>` operator with `std::getline`_? Are you referring to the `getline(cin, input);` line?

Comment: I typically mean what I say.  When I say replace "the >> operator" with std::getline, I am, obviously, referring to the >> operator, and not the existing call to std::getline(). You only have one function in the shown code that uses both, and that's what I was referring by "mixing together both std::getline and the >> operator".